# Get Top 5 Products in Each Category and Subcategory using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in my ASP.NET 4.5 web project. I have a table of products, each product with its category and sub-category. A category might not have a sub-category.

Table Products

- id
- name
- category_id
- subcategory_id
- date

Table Categories

- category_id
- parent_category_id

if the category has a `parent_category_id = 0`, it's a parent category, else it's a sub category of another category on that same table.

I want to create a query in **Entity Framework** to retrieve the top 5 products for each subcategory by date from the newest one to the oldest one.

At the end, I want to build tables that show the top 5 latest products for each subcategory.

A product can belogn to only one subcategory.

There are answers for this type of question with one category, but without sub-categories. My question is specific for that specific database structure. Thanks.

Comment: `If the product doesn't have a sub category, I want to show a the top 5 for the category` , My question is which category ? ? ?

and you say `else if it has a subcategory, I want to show the top 5 for that subcategory and not for the whole category.` My question is  which subcategory ? the very first product's category ?

Comment: I will make it simple (I will update the question to make it simple). I want the top five products by date (descending) for each subcategory. Every product will belong to only one subcategory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the code for Top 5 products using `lembda expressions`

```
YourEntities DBContext = new YourEntities();

List<Category> categories = DBContext.categories.Where(d=> d.category_id!=null).ToList();
List<Product> prodcuts = null;
foreach (var item in categories)
{
    prodcuts = DBContext.Products.Where(d => d.category_id== item.category_id)
                 .OrderByDescending(d => d.date)
                                 .Take(5)
                                 .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is there an option to do it i one query other than using iteration? I prefer that.

Comment: The second iteration will override the first products, am I right?

Comment: i don't think you can do it in one iteration , because first you want all the categories and then you want the products.

Yes it will `overwrite` them. it depends on your data binding how you want to persist them. Make another list or array and the products in it or bind the lists directly from here.

Answer (score 3):

```
var q= context.Categories
   .Where( c => c.parent_category_id != 0  )
   .Select( c=> new {
        c.categoryName,
        Products = c.products.OrderByDesc(p => p.DateUpdated)
            .Take (5)
            .Select( p => new {
                p.name,
                p.price
            })
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't take five from each subcategory, but rather 5  from all the products ordered by date

Comment: What is name of products navigation properties in category for subcategories relation?