# Get top n records with top m of relative table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a table `Categories` and `Products`. One category can have multiple products and I want to get TOP 5 products and TOP 3 categories for each product. I tried

```
entity.Categories.Include("Products").Take(3)
```

But output of this is 3 Categories and all products under them. I tried

```
entity.Categories.Take(5).Include("Products").Take(3)
```

But of course it won't work because `Include` can't be called in `Take`. So what could be the solution? Please suggest.

Comment: You want top five products for each top 3 category or you want top five products among all 3 top category?

Comment: Whatever, number is not my concern. Can you please suggest query of either?

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin have you looked at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939528/get-top-5-products-in-each-category-and-subcategory-using-entity-framework

Comment: @Arvaan bro. I have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved it

```
var result = entity.Categories.Select
                         (
                            cats => new
                                {   
                                    cats.CategoryName,
                                    cats.Description,
                                    Products = cats.Products.Take(3)
                                }
                         ).Take(5);
```